# Bootstrap grid alignment not displaying properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have written a bootstrap code as follows -

```css
.panel-heading {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: white !important;
}

span.dpi1 {
  color: crimson;
}

span.dpi2 {
  color: red;
}
table,td,tr{
  border-top-color:
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-body" style="margin-left: 10px;">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Enter <span class="dpi1">*</span></label>
            <input id="searchText" type="text" size="50"  autofocus="autofocus" />
            <button id="searchButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Search</button>
          </div>
          <div class="pull-right">
            <label><span class="dpi2">* Mandatory</span></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div>
      <div class="row pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="expand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down">Expand All</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up">Collapse All</span></button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="panel-group accord" id="showAgain">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseA"><span style="color: white">Summary</span></a></div>
            <div id="collapseA" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="panel-group accord">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseB"><span style="color: white">Information</span></a></div>
              <div id="collapseB" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th></th>
                          <th>xx</th>
                          <th>xxx</th>
                          <th>xxx</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Customer No</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>First Name</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Address</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Contact No.</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Email</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="panel-group accord">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseC"><span style="color: white">Information</span></a></div>
              <div id="collapseC" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                          <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                          <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="panel-group accord">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"><span style="color: white">Information</span></a></div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="panel-group accord">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2"><span style="color: white">Information</span></a></div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

All the rows are coming properly but the second one which is having two panels is not properly aligned with the other rows and the display looks like this -

[image]

The second row is not aligned properly. Can someone help me to align it correctly with the other rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't understand the right meaning of the question , are you looking for this

```css
.panel-heading {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
 border-top-left-radius: 3px;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
 text-decoration: none !important;
 color: white !important;
}
span.dpi1 {
 color: crimson;
}
span.dpi2 {
 color: red;
}
table, td, tr {
 border-top-color:
}
.accord {
 margin-top:15px;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-body" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Enter <span class="dpi1">*</span></label>
            <input id="searchText" type="text" size="50"  autofocus="autofocus" />
            <button id="searchButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Search</button>
          </div>
          <div class="pull-right">
            <label><span class="dpi2">* Mandatory</span></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 pull-right text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="expand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down">Expand All</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up">Collapse All</span></button>
      </div>


        <div class="panel-group accord" id="showAgain">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseA"><span style="color: white">Summary</span></a></div>
            <div id="collapseA" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="panel-group accord">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseB"><span style="color: white">Information</span></a></div>
              <div id="collapseB" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th></th>
                          <th>xx</th>
                          <th>xxx</th>
                          <th>xxx</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Customer No</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>First Name</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Address</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Contact No.</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b>Email</b></td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="panel-group accord">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseC"><span style="color: white">Information</span></a></div>
              <div id="collapseC" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                          <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                          <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-group accord">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"><span style="color: white">Information</span></a></div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-group accord">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2"><span style="color: white">Information</span></a></div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                        <th>XXXXXXX</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                        <td>XXXXXXX</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap, a `.row` must be wrapped into a `.container` or a `.container-fluid`. You should add 2 `.container-fluid` as in [this Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/xCTN8NxXQs)
That doesn't solve the problem described in your question: you should also add `.col-xs-12` (xs or another width interval) as direct child of each `.row`. Once it's done, you should move "grid modifiers" like `.pull-right` from `.row` to those column elements; otherwise I'm pretty sure it doesn't play nice with Bootstrap grid.

See [Grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

> - Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.
> - Predefined grid classes like .row and .col-xs-4 are available for quickly making grid layouts. Less mixins can also be used for more semantic layouts.
> - etc

Comment: But I want to have full width display, not the boxed as it comes with container. Any workaround for that?

Comment: I edited my answer: `.container-fluid` will create a _fluid_ grid (full width). You should also have .col(-sth) as direct child(ren) of .row elements. tl;dr simple grid: `.container(-fluid)>.row>.col(-rwd)-[1..12]`. Nested grid: `.container(-fluid)>.row>.col(-rwd)-[1..12]>.row>.col(-rwd)-[1..12]`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one wrapper row class for col-md-4 and col-md-8 in order to get those div properly aligned and on the full view if you do not want to wrap things on container.
Do this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
```

Instead of

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
```